# Parse about 700 lines of text, split the lines up and use them as variables?

Tags: java, parsing

Instead of having to go through 700-800 lines of text, each line being some variation of:

```
-5,-8,0:2.0
```

I have a method I have to pass each line to, which is `anotherclass.setBlock(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, id)`. So for the above example, it would be:

```
anotherclass.setBlock(x-5, y-8, 0, 2);
```

Is there any way to parse through every line of text and do this? I've been searching for ages, and it's either because I can't find the right way to word this or I just can't find the answer at all)

I've tried doing it manually, but after 100 lines, it started to feel really inefficient. I can't really use for loops as the coordinates aren't consecutive (or rather, they are, but only for 1 or 2 lines).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import static java.lang.Double.parseDouble;
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import static java.util.regex.Pattern.compile;

...

public static void main(String[] args) {
  BufferedReader r = null;
  try {
    r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"), "UTF-8"));
    final Pattern p = compile("(.+?),(.+?),(.+?):(.+)");
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
      final Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
      if (!m.matches())
        throw new RuntimeException("Line in invalid format: " + line);
      anotherclass.setBlock(parseInt(m.group(1)), parseInt(m.group(2)), 
          parseInt(m.group(3)), parseDouble(m.group(4)));
    }  
  }
  catch (IOException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
  finally { try { if (r != null) r.close(); } catch (IOEXception e) {} }
}
```